# GridView External Paging

Tags: asp.net, gridview, paging, web-controls

I'm looking to create a GridView with the paging hidden, but paging still allowed. Then, I'd like to create my own paging buttons external the GridView and have those page through the data. Essentially, this is to create a scrollable gridview with a sticky pager at the bottom that I can customize to fit the look, feel, and functionality required in my site. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this? I haven't found much in my searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a repeater with custom paging or define your own user control for this requirement.Check
[this article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=345) on how to do this with a repeater control.
**Update:** 
[This](http://www.mostlydevelopers.com/blog/post/2008/08/07/custom-gridview-paging.aspx) might help

**Update** [Fixed headers](http://www.shailwx.com/2009/12/fixed-gridview-headers-with-jquery/), [Client side pagination using jQuery](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37100/Client-Side-Gridview-Pagination-using-JQuery)

Comment: I'd prefer to use the prepackaged functionality with GridView, as that seems pretty performance ready. Is it possible to do this/am I wrong about the performance?

Comment: Repeater is a widely used control. What performance are you referring to ? The performance would greatly depend upon your database query (how many records you fetch) or do you mean client wise? (updated my answer with custom paging for gridview) although it might require a lot of work.

Comment: Maybe this will help clarify what I'm looking for. I need sorting on the entire dataset, pagination, and speed of data display (could be a large dataset as well, possibly a couple 1000 records). The header/sorting and footer/pagination need to be "sticky" in relation to the center data table, which will be scrolling. I was considering a cached response instead of an SQL pull on every page/sort, which I believe GridView handles. Also, GridView handles the other functions except sticky head/foot. Does repeater provide these functionalities as well?

Comment: You have to weight your pros & cons depending on your requirement. If you fetch results per page (10 rows) I think the results will be quite fast. You can also try client side pagination with jQuery. There is also an article on fixed headers which you can modify to include the footer as well.(Updated answer)

Comment: Thanks for all the help. This definitely gives me some options to look at.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was answered and is really old now, but I was having a lot of trouble with this and did not find the accepted answer completely helpful, mostly because I did not want to create a new control.

I found that you can do this quite easily actually, and here is how.

I created my gridview inside an updatepanel. I load the data for the grid on a button click I am not showing and then place the dataobject into the viewstate. Then I add a pagerSetting as such:

```
<PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" Visible="false" />
```

Then I added 4 buttons, a label and a text box to a div that I chose to expose to the server:

```
    <div runat="server" id="divPageControls" style="width:100%;margin-bottom:1%;margin-top:1%;display:none;">
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnFirst" Text="First" CssClass="ReOrderButtons" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />&nbsp;
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnPrev" Text="Previous" CssClass="ReOrderButtons" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />&nbsp;
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnNext" Text="Next" CssClass="ReOrderButtons" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />&nbsp;
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnLast" Text="Last" CssClass="ReOrderButtons" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />&nbsp;<br /><br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPageIndex"  AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="priceQuote_TextBoxStyle" style="margin-left:20px;float:none;width:4%;text-align:center;" ></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblOfPages"></asp:Label>
    </div>
```

Now Everything was in place, All I had to do was add the event handlers.

```
    Protected Sub btnFirst_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFirst.Click
        _mainView.PageIndex = 0
        _mainView_PageIndexChanging(_mainView, New System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs(_mainView.PageIndex))
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnLast_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLast.Click
        _mainView.PageIndex = _mainView.PageCount - 1
        _mainView_PageIndexChanging(_mainView, New System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs(_mainView.PageIndex))
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnPrev_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrev.Click
        _mainView.PageIndex -= 1
        _mainView_PageIndexChanging(_mainView, New System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs(_mainView.PageIndex))
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnNext_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
        _mainView.PageIndex += 1
        _mainView_PageIndexChanging(_mainView, New System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs(_mainView.PageIndex))
    End Sub

    Protected Sub txtPageIndex_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtPageIndex.TextChanged
        If fromInternal = False Then
            If txtPageIndex.Text <> "" And IsNumeric(txtPageIndex.Text) Then
                If CInt(txtPageIndex.Text - 1) < _mainView.PageCount - 1 And CInt(txtPageIndex.Text - 1) >= 0 Then
                    _mainView.PageIndex = CInt(txtPageIndex.Text - 1)
                    _mainView_PageIndexChanging(_mainView, New System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs(_mainView.PageIndex))
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub _mainView_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles _mainView.PageIndexChanging
        _mainView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
        _mainView.DataSource = ViewState("currProducts")
        _mainView.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub _mainView_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _mainView.DataBound
        If _mainView.PageCount > 1 Then
            divPageControls.Style("display") = "block"

            If _mainView.PageIndex = 0 Then
                btnFirst.Style("display") = "none"
                btnPrev.Style("display") = "none"
                btnLast.Style("display") = "inline"
                btnNext.Style("display") = "inline"
            ElseIf _mainView.PageIndex > 0 And _mainView.PageIndex < _mainView.PageCount - 1 Then
                btnFirst.Style("display") = "inline"
                btnPrev.Style("display") = "inline"
                btnLast.Style("display") = "inline"
                btnNext.Style("display") = "inline"
            ElseIf _mainView.PageIndex = _mainView.PageCount - 1 Then
                btnLast.Style("display") = "none"
                btnNext.Style("display") = "none"
                btnFirst.Style("display") = "inline"
                btnPrev.Style("display") = "inline"
            End If

            fromInternal = True
            txtPageIndex.Text = CStr(_mainView.PageIndex + 1)
            lblOfPages.Text = "of " & CStr(_mainView.PageCount - 1)

        End If
    End Sub
```

After all that, when the buttons are pressed the index of the girdview's page is changed and then passed to the view's PageIndexChanging event. This is working wonderfully for me and I hope someone else can use it.

Bear in mind I did not show the async triggers for the update panel or any of the other nuances, however I don't think they are necessary for paging, unless you are using an update panel like I am.